Showing only one record when using delphi adoquery eoAsyncexcute. How to use asyncExcute and asyncFetch
I use TADOQuery in Delphi XE7 to execute a select query inside a large table so I use the property "eoAsyncexcute" and "eoAsyncFetch" in exceuteOptions to query and fetch async the records to TDBGrid.
The problem is :
It show only one record in DBGrid (There is a lot of records in result)! I can use mouse scroll to see other records but DBGrid only shows one by one. TDBGrid scrollbar is large that show there is lots of records in it but only shows one record!
I set the CatchSize of TADOQuery to 50 AND also change the cursorType to ctDynamic and CursorLocation to clUseServer : no success
When I remove "eoAsyncexecute" in exceuteOptions property, it shows all records.
What is the problem? I googled a lot but find nothing?
Thanks

Also it shows an error (only at first query execution):


